# Acquitted and absolved used together

Tags: usage

Is the second part of this sentence redundant?

> He was **acquitted of** and **absolved from** all the charges of corruption

Since **acquit** and **absolve** mean almost the same thing, why use both in the sentence?

Comment: "acquit and absolve mean almost the same thing" - 'almost' does not mean 'exactly'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Acquitted* is primarily a *legal* term (he was found not to have broken the relevant law under which he was charged).

*Absolved* is primarily a *moral judgement* (he was not found to be blameworthy, he didn't do anything "improper")

Comment: I don't know if it still exists, but there used to be a "Not Proven" judgement in Scottish law. Which was invariably the verdict given when wishing to imply *There wasn't enough evidence to **prove** guilt on the specific charges, but the court has reason to suspect crimes were in fact committed by the accused*. On the other hand, if the judge said *I'm acquitting and absolving you of all charges*, that would be taken as implying *no blame whatsoever* attaches to the defendant. I don't think it's exactly a "standard" legalese pairing though - not like ***aid and abet***.